# For unit complex numbers $z$ and $w$ and the quaternion $j$, when does $zj\bar{w}=j$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions

I'm trying to figure out for which unit complex $z,w \in S^1$ does $zj\bar{w}=j$ for the quaternion $j$.

I was trying to solve this by setting $z=a+bi$ and $w=c+di$, so

$zj\bar{w}=(a+bi)j(c-di)=(aj+bk)(c-di)=(ac-bd)j+(bc+ad)k$

Setting this equal to $j$ we must have

(1) ac-bd=1

(2) bc+ad=0

Multiplying (1) by $b$ and (2) by $a$ and subtracting (1) from (2) we get

$b^2d-a^2d=b \implies d(b^2-a^2) = b$.

> This doesn't seem to tell me anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugging $a = -\frac{bc}{d}$ into your first equation you get

$$
-\frac{bc^2}{d} - bd =1 \;\;\;\; \Longrightarrow\;\;\;\; b(c^2+d^2)= -d
$$

but noting that $z$ and $w$ have unit length, this tell us that $c^2+d^2=1$ and therefore $b=-d$.  Then this tell us that $a = c$.  Therefore we have that $z =\overline{w}$.  In other words, the transformations $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}$ that fix $j$ are of the form

$$
(z, q) \;\; \to \;\; zqz.
$$

Comment: I see, good catch! Note that this doesn't address the case $d=0$.

Comment: @TuoTuo This is really simple to amend.  If $d=0$, go back to the original equation.  Then it reduces to $(ac + bci)j = j$ which turns into $acj + bck = j$, hence $ac = 1$ and $bc=0$ implying that $b=0$.  Therefore $a=c$ since they're of unit length and only work in the cases if $a=c=1$ and $a=c=-1$.

Comment: I agree, I was just noting it for reference in case anyone else views the page.